# Ошибка при считывании и обработке изображения полученного через requests.get().content | UnicodeDecodeError: и AttributeError: |

Tags: python, изображения, requests, обработка-изображений

---

## Описание проблемы:

Всех приветствую!
Столкнулся со следующим, когда получаю изображение через `requests.get().content`
и пытаюсь дальше обработать изображение, выдаёт ошибки которые описал внизу.
Прошу помочь, перепробовал уже много вариантов.

---

### Основной код

> Я думаю что проблема в первых двух строчках
>
> > `#image: получает ссылку на изображение`
> > `#rad: получает int число`

```
    def add_corners(image, rad):  
        img = requests.get(image, 'r', verify=True).content
        im = Image.open(img)
        circle = Image.new('L', (rad * 2, rad * 2), 0)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(circle)
        draw.ellipse((0, 0, rad * 2, rad * 2), fill=255)
        alpha = Image.new('L', im.size, 'white')
        w, h = im.size
        alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, 0, rad, rad)), (0, 0))
        alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, rad, rad, rad * 2)), (0, h - rad))
        alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, 0, rad * 2, rad)), (w - rad, 0))
        alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, rad, rad * 2, rad * 2)), (w - rad, h - rad))
        im.putalpha(alpha)
        return im
```

##### Вывод в консоль:

`File "---путь к файлу---", line 29, in add_corners` 
`im = Image.open(img)`
`File "---путь к библиотеке---\PIL\Image.py", line 3068, in open`
`fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")`
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

---

#### *Попытки решения:*

**Решил обойти таким путем:**
`im = requests.get(image, 'rb', verify=True).content`
**Получил следующую ошибку:**
`File "D:\APP-PDF\APP-PDF\Generator_PDF.py", line 32, in add_corners` 
`alpha = Image.new('L', im.size, 'white')` 
`AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'size'`

---

> P.S. Если пробовать открывать файл через:
> `Image.open('image.png')` 
> то работает код как нужно, если файл есть в директории.

Comment: Вы пытались заменить `img = requests.get(image, 'r', verify=True).content` на `img = requests.get(image, 'r', verify=True, stream=True).raw` или `im = Image.open(img)` на `im = Image.open(img.encode('utf-8'))`?

Comment: @re1von, да, пробовал в обоих случаях ошибка  в первом `AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'size' `   во втором `AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'encode' `

Comment: Модуль io не пробывыли?

Comment: @СергейШашко, нет не пробовал. Есть идеи как правильно его внедрить в этот код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот прямо из [документации](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/) библиотеки `requests` пример, как нужно открывать изображение, полученное через запрос:

```py
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

i = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
```

У вас получается, что в `Image.open(img)` содержание `img` воспринимается как имя файла, поэтому выходят такие ошибки.